# How can I see the full layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` in `Android` that has this structure:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
      <EditText></EditText>
      <TextView></TextView>
   </LinearLayout>

   //Here more LinearLayout similar to the LinearLayout that I put above

</LinearLayout>
```

But I have so much `EditText` and `LinearLayout` in my layout that I can't see the full layout in the screen of my mobile phone. It won't be a problem if I could move the screen to see the full layout, but I couldn't. I just can see the elements that enter in the screen, the rest aren't accesible.

I saw a lot of questions but any of them let me fix my error.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be better if Can you provide the full layout XML code so people can see where the problem is

Comment: @Want2bExpert I didn't add it because it's very extend (it's always the same but with different Text in the EditText) so I though it wasn't necesary. Do you really think it is necesary?

Comment: You're partly right but not many people will know that. I wanted to suggest ScrollView as provided for you in one of the answers but don't want to give false info and from my experience, some people on here are sometimes quick to down vote but slow to up vote

Comment: @Want2bExpert Well... I though it was clearly explained in the question but I'm grateful that you correct me. It's nice to hear critical opinions to improve for my next question. And you are right, here there are a lot of people that gives free down votes.

Comment: Tip: I know that isn't the best practice, but you can separate your layout with include pads, if you want to see all layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ScrollView` as root

```
 <ScrollView 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/scroll" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout>
              <EditText></EditText>
              <TextView></TextView>
           </LinearLayout>

       //Here more LinearLayout similar to the LinearLayout that I put above        
       </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: yeah, you're right :) I forgot it. Deleted my comment to not make confusion

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I wanted! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Choose a **ScrollView** as container for your layout

Like this:

```
    <ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/scroll" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout>
          <EditText></EditText>
          <TextView></TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

   //Here more LinearLayout similar to the LinearLayout that I put above        
   </LinearLayout>
```

This is the referece about [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Try packaging your most outer `LinearLayout` with a `ScrollView`**. This will allow your users to scroll down and see all the content.

[`ScrollView` example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/)

Good luck!